# Perl Syntax and Regex and Distinct Characters within a Range

Tags: regex, pcre

Hello Stackflow community,

I am trying to understand Regex in Perl Syntax and I ran into confusion.

Goal: Take all values within A-Z, and find "AAAA" or "ABAAA" or "ZaZZZ"

What I am currently getting: any four characters from a-z "ABCD"

Wrong Code so far(substituted value for x):

```
regex r

r.compile ("[a-z]{4, }") 
if r.findfirst(`x`) then return true else return false
```

Thank you for your time. I have been researching this for quite some time at a new job and I want to become adept in this arena.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: What language are you using? The code you've shown isn't Perl.

Comment: Also, can you describe what combinations of characters do you want to match? The three examples you gave can be matched by `^(AB?AAA|ZaZZZ)$`, but I guess that's not the whole story.

Comment: I am using a software called dataflux using "Perl-compatible syntax for regular expressions."

Comment: I want to be able to match values from an open text field. This could be any combination of letters. I would like to find at least 4 of any letter a-z distinctly.

Comment: PCRE is not Perl -- assuming it's even PCRE that's being used -- though in both, `[a-z]{4,}` matches four or more lower cases letters. However, you used `[a-z]{4, }` which is interpreted as `[a-z]\{4, \}` in Perl. Neither expression will match `x`.

Comment: Thank you Ikegami I did not know that PCRE is different than Perl. The statement I wrote returns, it just counts ABCD as a true statement. Is there a way to make the Range A-Z Distinct for each letter?